# How to identify and delete a tkinter canvas drawing through tags kept in a tags list?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tags

I'm trying to delete a rectangle from the canvas through a second button click through making use of a list of tags. See the function 'insert_or_delete_cells' below. Although the code keeps the tags list up-to-date, it does not delete the rectangle itself from the canvas. It appears from the print statements that the code does not retrieve the id of the rectangle, so nothing is deleted. How to improve this code?

```
import tkinter as tk

def insert_or_delete_cells():
    def xyposition(event):
        x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        x_matrix=int(x//cell)
        y_matrix=int(y//cell)
        x0 = x_matrix*cell+1
        y0 = y_matrix*cell+1
        mark = str(x_matrix)+str(y_matrix)
        c = cell-1
        if mark not in tags_list:
            rect = canvas.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x0+c,y0+c, width=0, fill='green', tags = mark)
            tags_list.append(mark)
            print('new cell id: ', rect, 'new cell tag: ', mark)
        else:
            r=canvas.find_withtag(mark)
            print('removed cell id: ', r, 'removed cell tag: ', mark)
            canvas.delete(mark) # canvas.delete(r) doesn't work neither
            tags_list.remove(mark)
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", xyposition)

def stop_insert_cells():
    canvas.unbind('<Button-1>')

# MAIN
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
n=30
m=30
cell=10
w = n*cell
h = m*cell

# canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width = w, height = h, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.place(x=20, y=20)

# border canvas
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,w-1,h-1, outline = 'black')

# cell filling
tags_list = []
start_insert_button = tk.Button(root, text='start', command = insert_or_delete_cells)
stop_insert_button = tk.Button(root, text = 'stop', command = stop_insert_cells)

stop_insert_button.pack(side='bottom')
start_insert_button.pack(side='bottom')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a tag, you are using strings that look like integers. Tags can be anything at all *except* strings that look like integers, since tkinter won't know whether you're referring to a tag or an item id.

Your code will work if you make sure that `mark` is not composed only of digits. For example, changing the definition of `mark` to something like the following will allow your code to work:

```
    mark=f"mark-{x_matrix},{y_matrix}"
```

From the canonical tcl/tk documentation:

> Each item may also have any number of tags associated with it. A tag is just a string of characters, and **it may take any form except that of an integer**. For example, “x123” is OK but “123” is not. The same tag may be associated with many different items. This is commonly done to group items in various interesting ways; for example, all selected items might be given the tag “selected”.